# CSS issue in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My website contains drop-down menus at the top right corner of the screen. The drop-down  is displayed fine, but when I hover over elements within the drop-down, IE renders them incorrecty. Firefox, however, displays them the way I want.
The website is [http://www.textsensor.com/test](https://web.archive.org/web/20100920190736/http://textsensor.com:80/test/). Can anybody tell me what is causing the issue in IE?

Here are the details. Each parent at top has a child `<div>` which contains child elements in a `<ul>`. I am displaying them inline with width of the `<div>` container fixed, so that two of them are being displayed in one line. Each child `<li>` contains two images and an anchor in between. These two images are providing rounded corners, whereas the anchor contains a `<span>`, which in turn contains the text of the sub-menu item. When the mouse moves over the `<span>`, I am showing its parent anchor sibling images through javascript, and also setting its bg-image to white. Images are not aligned correctly and `<span>` tag got down about 10px from top on IE only. The jQuery used is listed below:

```
   $("#jsddm li ul li a span").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings("img").css("visibility", 'visible');
        $(this).parent().css("border-bottom", "#a00 5px double");
    }, function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings("img").css("visibility", 'hidden');
        $(this).parent().css("border-bottom", "none");
    });
```

Html of one menu item is:

```
<li><img src='images/submenuImg1.png' class='leftsubImg'>
<a href="pricerates.php"><span>Price Rates</span></a>
<img src='images/submenuImg3.png' class='rightsubImg'>
</li>
```

When I mouseover span leftsubImg, rightsubImg will be visile and also bg of span is set to be an image repeating in x. Issue that is causing trouble is that span is having margin of about 12px from top and it is about 5px below images on its left and right.

IE output is [image: http://i46.tinypic.com/2858bl.gif]

Cheers

Ayaz Alavi

Comment: CSS issue in IE? No, it can't be!

Comment: Whenever I get problems in IE8, i just use the IE7 compatiblity tag - you'd be surprised how many problems that get rid of. (Indeed, i could work the error out, but i'm lazy)

Comment: @Jamie: Your site(s) will most likely will stop rendering correctly in IE10.  Let's hope you've resolved your laziness by then ;-)

Comment: setting its `bg-image` to `white`!? White, it seems, is now not a color, but an image...

Comment: Let's let the snark go and get to the helpful.

Comment: Could you please paste in some example HTML? Your description leaves me wondering a bit. (Pasting a quick snippet here for posterity will make it nice for future readers.)

Comment: Html of one menu item is:  
 <li><img src='images/submenuImg1.png' class='leftsubImg'><a href="pricerates.php"><span>Price Rates</span></a><img src='images/submenuImg3.png' class='rightsubImg'></li>
  When I mouseover span leftsubImg, rightsubImg will be visile and also bg of span is set to be an image repeating in x. Issue that is causing trouble is that span is having margin of about 12px from top and it is about 5px below images on its left and right.

Comment: IE output is http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2858bl&s=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8 and IE 7 issue is fixed by using following Conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
.leftsubImg , .rightsubImg
{
    margin-bottom:-13px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style>
.leftsubImg , .rightsubImg
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

It moved images at correct position. Now in IE6 I have got z-index issue that is menus are not moving in front of fat guy picture.

Answer (score 1):

Rounded corners: you're doing it wrong.

*Never* use an `<img>` for purely stylistic content (such as rounded corners). It sure as hell won't provide useful information to a screen-reader, or a user with stylesheets disabled. Use background images instead.

Also, `.hide()` is not what you want to do to the images: doing so removes them from the flow of the document, meaning the span elements shift. Use `.css('visibility','hidden')` instead.

In fact, you don't need javascript at all. Take a look at http://www.jsfiddle.net/TeTLw/. The button doesn't look quite right, but it should work cross-browser.

To make the button look right, you need to make [your image](http://www.textsensor.com/test/images/submenuImg3.png) longer: Have it like this:

```
 ____________________________________
|                                     \
|                                      |
|____________________________________ /
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with using IMG for rounded corners etc, this would be backwardly compatible with older browsers. I agree you *shouldn't* do it, but there is nothing **wrong** with it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice it worked but i am still getting margin from top of abut 15px on the span containing text. Although images are positioned fixed and menu is much stable.

Comment: your quit right in using one image only and I did that in the beginning but my sub-menu items are different in length for e.g. one of my shortest menu item is say 5 char in length and and largest menu item is 25 char in length so one image was not working for all of my menu items bcuz image was repeating in x direction for larger menu items. If you know any technique that allows auto stretching of bg image so that all items can accomodate inside one image then this technique might be usefull.

Comment: Did you read what I said? All you need to do is change your "submenuImg3.png" image to look the the ascii art in my answer: one edge flat, the other round. The one at the URL I gave you will then work.

Comment: IE7, IE8 are fixed by moving images. IE6 is not displaying menus in front of image at bottom(fat guy picture). It a z-index issue. Can anybody tell how can I move my image in front?

Comment: Make an image that looks like the one I drew above, and tell me the URL. I'll update my demo to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the whitespace between the li elements in the source?

Just a quick guess, it might be the IE whitespace bug...

Also I'm currently getting javascript errors in IE..

Comment: I tried to remove whitespaces but it didnot helped. Now issue is, span is down about 5px and have topmargin of about 10px. see image I attached in my question.